# Invalid Document Element 'type': Character content other than whitespace is not allowed because the content type is 'element-only'

Tags: magento2

New to Magento2
I changed default mode into developer mode
after that my back end not working 
in terminal its shows error when i try to run commands
Invalid Document

Invalid Document 
Element 'type': Character content other than white space is not allowed because the content type is 'element-only'.
Line: 6

Element 'arguments': Character content other than white space is not allowed because the content type is 'element-only'.
Line: 7

Element 'arguments': Character content other than white space is not allowed because the content type is 'element-only'.
Line: 7

Element 'type': Character content other than white space is not allowed because the content type is 'element-only'.
Line: 6

Element 'type': Character content other than white space is not allowed because the content type is 'element-only'.
Line: 11

Element 'arguments': Character content other than white space is not allowed because the content type is 'element-only'.
Line: 12

Element 'arguments': Character content other than white space is not allowed because the content type is 'element-only'.
Line: 12

Element 'arguments': Character content other than white space is not allowed because the content type is 'element-only'.
Line: 12

Element 'type': Character content other than white space is not allowed because the content type is 'element-only'.
Line: 11

Comment: check this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/306592/85907

Answer (score 0):

you have a copy code from somewhere so some character are also copied you can find this type of character using ctr+a and remove it most of character added before line